# DrRacket Merging Lists of Structures

Tags: racket

I am wondering how to merge lists to make into one big list. For example
Lets say we are given a struct, 
`(define-struct fruits (type number))`
Basically given this

```
(list 
     (list (make-fruits 'Apple 4) (make-fruits 'Orange 3) (make-fruits 'Pears 5))
     (list (make-fruits 'Peach 4))
     (list (make-fruits 'Kiwi 5) (make-fruits 'Banana 2)))
```

How can I merge all these list structures into one big list? Any way using local, map, foldr, filter and not using recursion.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket
(define-struct fruits (type number) #:transparent)

(apply append
       (list 
        (list (make-fruits 'Apple 4) (make-fruits 'Orange 3) (make-fruits 'Pears 5))
        (list (make-fruits 'Peach 4))
        (list (make-fruits 'Kiwi 5) (make-fruits 'Banana 2))))
```

Result:

```
(list (fruits 'Apple 4) (fruits 'Orange 3) (fruits 'Pears 5) (fruits 'Peach 4) (fruits 'Kiwi 5) (fruits 'Banana 2))
```